# How to get Magento Invoice & shipment comment visible on frontend through SOAP API?

Tags: magento-1.8, php, magento-community, soap

I am writing a custom order handling script for magento CE. If a new order is picked up by the script through cron it should create an invoice and notify the user and send a comment. I use the SOAP api for this purpose.
This works when sending an email, but how can I make the comment visible to the user on the frontend?
If I manually login to Magento admin, I can add a comment to an order and then check `Visible on Frontend`. 
I would like the comments I add with `sales_order_invoice.create` and `sales_order_shipment.create` to be visible to the customer in the Frontend the same way. I know that is not possible with default settings in the backend, but I would like to do that. 
If this is really hard to do, I would at least like the comments added with `sales_order.addComment` to be visible to the customer on the frontend just as when I manually comment and check `Visible on Frontend`.

Here is my code for the SOAP proxy:

```
class magentoProxyHandler{

    protected $proxy;
    protected $session;

    function __construct(){

        $this->proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.magento.nl/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
        $this->session = $this->proxy->login('change_order', 'password');
    }

    function __destruct(){

        $this->proxy->endSession($this->session);

    }

    function addComment($orderId, $status, $comment = '', $notifyCustomer = true){

        $orderId = ($orderId > 100000000 ? $orderId : $orderId + 100000000);
        $notify = $notifyCustomer ? true : false;

        $changeOrder = array('orderIncrementId' => $orderId, 'status' => $status, 'comment'=> $comment, 'notify'=> $notify);

        return $this->proxy->call($this->session, 'sales_order.addComment', $changeOrder);

    }


    function createInvoice($orderId, $status, $comment = 'Invoice ready', $notifyCustomer = true){

        $orderId = ($orderId > 100000000 ? $orderId : $orderId + 100000000);
        $notify = $notifyCustomer ? true : false;
        return $this->proxy->call($this->session, 'sales_order_invoice.create', array($orderId, array(), $comment, true, true));

    }

    function shipOrder($orderId, $status, $comment = 'Order shipped', $notifyCustomer = true){

        $orderId = ($orderId > 100000000 ? $orderId : $orderId + 100000000);
        $notify = $notifyCustomer ? true : false;
        return $this->proxy->call($this->session, 'sales_order_shipment.create', array($orderId, array(), $comment, true, true));

    }


} //end of class
```

I know I can do some little improvements to this code, this was simply for testing the the soap API.

I also asked this question in stackoverflow. I hope thats OK.
If It get answered there, I'll post the answer here. Hope you guys can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Ok , I found out this flag has to be set in database: `is_visible_on_front` . Is there anyway to pass this through the SOAP api? Of course I tried adding it to the call, as well as `isVisibleOnFront` but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

OK I found out how to do it, had to change a little code:

1. I coppied `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php` to `/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php`
2. I changed the method addComment:

   ```
   public function addComment($orderIncrementId, $status, $comment = '', $notify = false, $showOnFront = true)
   {
       $order = $this->_initOrder($orderIncrementId);

       $historyItem = $order->addStatusHistoryComment($comment, $status);
       $historyItem->setIsVisibleOnFront($showOnFront);
       $historyItem->setIsCustomerNotified($notify)->save();


       try {
           if ($notify && $comment) {
               $oldStore = Mage::getDesign()->getStore();
               $oldArea = Mage::getDesign()->getArea();
               Mage::getDesign()->setStore($order->getStoreId());
               Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend');
           }

           $order->save();
           $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail($notify, $comment);
           if ($notify && $comment) {
               Mage::getDesign()->setStore($oldStore);
               Mage::getDesign()->setArea($oldArea);
           }

       } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
           $this->_fault('status_not_changed', $e->getMessage());
       }

       return true;
   }
   ```
3. And then in my class:

   ```
   function addComment($orderId, $status, $comment = '', $notifyCustomer = true, $showOnFront = true){

       $orderId = ($orderId > 100000000 ? $orderId : $orderId + 100000000);
       $notify = $notifyCustomer ? true : false;

       $changeOrder = array('orderIncrementId' => $orderId, 'status' => $status, 'comment'=> $comment, 'notify'=> $notify, 'showOnFront' =>  $showOnFront);

       return $this->proxy->call($this->session, 'sales_order.addComment', $changeOrder);

   }
   ```

Works like a charm!
From what I've seen I can do the same thing in the shipment and invoice api files.

Comment: So, first of all: You copied the whole class to app/code/local for changing two lines. That's not very update-friendly. A rewrite with only the needed functin included would me more transparent. Second, you did not make comments about the changes in the file so I looked it up: you added one parameter $showOnFront = true and added the line $historyItem->setIsVisibleOnFront($showOnFront);

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes indeed I did. How would you suggest I rewrite only that method? I don't know how to do that... Regarding the changes I made, I guess I should have just stated which lines to change. I'll remember that for next time.

Comment: You can just make a new class that inherits the old one, then only change the method(s) you need to. This link may help: http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Or, search around for "magento overriding classes", there are other tutorials and articles out there.